# Why Gibbs energy change of a process can be negative at constant temperature and pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics

This question has been asked before, but the answers are not clear and satisfactory.
If the pressure and the temperature are constant then G would be always zero. How would then G have a value other than 0?

Comment: Why should G be always zero?

Comment: The difference in G between two sides of a reaction is not, in general, zero.

Answer (score 1):

G is a function of T and P, but also, in a mixture, the number of moles of each of the species in the mixture.  If these change because of a chemical reaction, G also changes (even at constant T and P).